# MonoTouch - .NET 4.0 on an iPhone

Tags: xamarin.ios

We've upgraded to MonoTouch 4.0 and the new MonoDevelop.

In order to get .NET 4.0 , do we need to enable a setting, or does MonoTouch automatically compile against the newest Mono ?

Everything has been working perfectly, iTunes has accepted all our [apps](http://click.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/stat?id=Cx%2a2tmwN8%2aQ&offerid=146261&type=3&subid=0&tmpid=1826&RD_PARM1=http%253A%252F%252Fitunes.apple.com%252Fus%252Fapp%252F40-bibles-and-commentaries%252Fid411577228%253Fmt%253D8%2526uo%253D4%2526partnerId%253D30), all without issue. We've released now nearly 70 apps made with MonoTouch and have thousands of users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MonoTouch 4 requires that you have previously installed Mono shared runtime 2.10.1 in order to install it.

Once you have installed Mono runtime, MonoDevelop and of course ios 4.3 sdk now you can install monotouch 4, once installed you are now able to get Net 4 love by creating a new iphone solution :) (yes you dont have to modify any settings)

Hope this helps

Alex

Comment: MonoTouch 4 doesn't require MD 2.6b1. The recommended IDE is the stable MD 2.4.2 from the updater, though the latest 2.6b1 from the updater should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from MonoTouch's website ( http://monotouch.net/Releases/MonoTouch_4/MonoTouch_4.0.0 ), it says "Core Mono Runtime upgraded to Mono 2.10" so it looks like dmcs ( http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.10 ) is included. I don't have MonoDevelop installed, but I might be able to help you out with my suggestion:

Look in Project ->  Options -> Build -> General -> Runtime Version (I couldn't post more than 2 links since I'm a new user.)

I hope this answers your question.